# How to list directories using SSH.NET?

Tags: c#, ssh, ssh.net

I need to list directories on my Ubuntu machine.

I did it with files, but I can't find similar solution for directories.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path)
{
    using (var sftpClient = new SftpClient(_host, _port, _username, _password))
    {
        sftpClient.Connect();
        var files = sftpClient.ListDirectory(path);
        return files.Select(f => f.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: files.Select(f => f.Name).Where(x=> x.IsDirectory)   and maybe ignore "." and ".."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Unix-like OSes, including Linux, [**directories are files**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22directories%20are%20files%22) - so your `ListDirectory` result will return "files" (in the traditional sense) and directories combined. You can filter those out by checking `IsDirectory`:

```
public List<String> GetFiles(string path)
{
    using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient( _host, _port, _username, _password ) )
    {
        client.Connect();
        return client
            .ListDirectory( path )
            .Where( f => !f.IsDirectory )
            .Select( f => f.Name )
            .ToList();
    }
}

public List<String> GetDirectories(string path)
{
    using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient( _host, _port, _username, _password ) )
    {
        client.Connect();
        return client
            .ListDirectory( path )
            .Where( f => f.IsDirectory )
            .Select( f => f.Name )
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

(I changed the return type to a concrete `List<T>` because if `ListDirectory` were to return a lazily-evaluated enumerable then the `using()` block would invalidate the parent `SftpClient` object before the operation had completed - the same reason you never return an `IQueryable<T>` from within a `using( DbContext )`)